# Removing everything after "?" python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I get an error when I try to get rid of everything behind the "?" in a set of scraped links:

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time 
from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/discover?ref=nav')
categories = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category-container')

category_links = []
for category_link in categories:
    category_links.append((str('https://www.kickstarter.com'),
                     category_link.find_element_by_class_name('bg-white').get_attribute('href')))
    print(category_links)
    for i in category_link:
    category_links2 = re.sub('?$', '', category_links)
    print(category_links2)
```

error:

> TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to iterate over `category_links`. `i` is the loop variable
2. You need to apply `re.sub` over `i`, not `category_links` because the latter is a list, and `re.sub` will not work on lists.
3. For a simple task like this, I recommend splitting on `?` with `str.split`:

---

```
for i in category_links:
    category_links2 = i[1].split('?')[-1]
    print(category_links2)
```

Comment: @nemja Show me what the tuple looks like.

Comment: [('https://www.kickstarter.com', 'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/art?ref=discover_index'), ('https://www.kickstarter.com', 'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/comics?ref=discover_index'), etc.

Comment: Yess, Works!! However, now I get the last part of the string. How do I get the first part? (Before the "?")

Comment: @nemja `i[1].split('?')[0]` instead of -1

Answer (score 2):

Why don't to just that...
if url is your link

```
url.split('?')[0]
```

Comment: Get the following error; AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: in that case just do something like that,  url[0].split('?')[0]